# One machine being server AND client with STunnel

Tags: sockets, client, stunnel

I know that STunnel can be set up as either server or client with the "client = no" or "client = yes" lines in the config file. Is there a way for a machine to be BOTH a server and client?

Answer (score 5):

It is much easier
you can simply You just have to set client=no under the [] (service) where stunnel works as a server and client=yes otherwise. 
You should also put service specific parameters like certificates where they
belong.

Something like:

```
[server1]
..
client=no

[client1]
..
client=yes
```

Comment: but make sure your client and server should not accept on same port number.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the configuration file path on the command line, see [`stunnel(8)`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/stunnel).

Comment: Does this mean I would need to start 2 STunnel services with 2 configuration files?

Answer (score 0):

As `/etc/stunnel/README` file says,

> "Files found under the /etc/stunnel directory that end with .conf are
>   used by stunnel4 service as configuration files, and each will be used
>   to start a daemon process setting up a tunnel with the given
>   configuration..."

I assume you can keep 2 separate config files there: one for server and another one for client. Than you'll have 2 daemons started.
You can find config file examples in a file `/usr/share/doc/stunnel4/examples/stunnel.conf-sample`

Answer (score 0):

### Stunnel Client Configurations

```
[client]
client = yes
accept = 7777
connect = 127.0.0.1:7777
```

"accept" will act as server
"connect" will act as client

### Stunnel Server Configurations

```
[server]
accept = 7777
connect = 127.0.0.1:7777
```

"accept" will act as client
"connect" will act as server